# Jquery dialog issue in IE11

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, dialog, jquery-ui-dialog

I have this piece of code to open a popup using jquery UI.

```
 $('#myId').dialog({
    autoopen:false,
    height:"550",
    width:"90%",
    closeOnEscape:true,
    modal:true,
    show:{
    effect:"fade",
    duration:500
    },
    clsoe:function(event,ui){
    $(this).dialog("destroy").remove();
    },
    hide{
    effect:"fade",
    duration:500
    },

    }).dialog("Open");
```

This code is working perfectly fine in IE 7 & 8 and in chrome.

But when I open the popup in IE11 the content of the pop up is appending the existing body rather than opening as a popup.
But when I click on popup **with the developer tools(F12) open** the code is **working fine** IE11 also, I have not find any errors in the code(F12 Console).

Please guide me how to make it work in IE11.
Thanks.

Comment: Are you missing a single quote after #myId

Comment: while asking question i missed it .. in code its proper..

Comment: I created a jsfiddle to try and replicate the problem. https://jsfiddle.net/qfzg1ym6/ But in IE 11 and Firefox the popup overlaps the preceding green div